# Seperate list of emails in php to a php array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, email

I have a form that submits to codeigniter email class and sends emails to my clients. I have a simple `to` input field.

```
<input type="text" name="to" class="form-control">
```

I want to be able to type multiple email addresses into this one field and send emails to them all at once. This is pretty simple in codeigniter I just need to get the emails into an array and placed in the `to` param in codeigniter.

So I want to be able to type something like the below into the field, submit it, break the post data into an array with the breaking point being `,` or a comma.

`someone@me.com, yournamehere@example.com, myself@myowndomain.com`

The above would need to go into an array such as this:

```
$list = array(
   'someone@me.com',
   'yournamehere@example.com',
   'myself@myowndomain.com,
);
```

My real question is, what is the fastest and cleanest way to break the regular post data from the input field `to` into an array by using `,` a comma as the breaking point.

Comment: Although there are many ways of doing this, one of which would be to simply use a combination of JS with a `+` button to add an additional input automatically, then using a `foreach` loop. You can also `explode()` and `foreach()` also. You might also need to use `trim()` should there happen to be any accidental whitespaces. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14541856/ that actually uses `implode()` instead of `explode()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP [explode()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp)  function. More decent manual in the PHP [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).
This is the idea but if you gonna receive these emails separated by comma in the backend, you should use $_GET or $_POST.

```
<?php
    //$str = $_POST['emails'];
    $str = "someone@me.com, yournamehere@example.com, myself@myowndomain.com";
    print_r (explode(",",$str));
    ?>
```

**Syntax:** *explode(separator,string,limit)*. In your case you want comma to be the separator so that's why the separator should be comma.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a go; it worked fine for me, while adding [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to remove all whitespace.

Plus, there is also a second method using a filtered method to help protect against [**XSS injection**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) using PHP's [`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) filter.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $to = $_POST['to'];
    $var = explode(',', $to);
    $me = "you@example.com";

foreach($var as $mailto){

    $mailto = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $mailto); // remove all whitespace

    $subject = 'Message subject ' . $name; // optional variable
    $message = "Hello there.";

    $headers = "From: {$me}\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: {$mailto}\r\n";

    mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }

} // brace for isset

?>

<form action="" method="post">

<input type="text" name="to" class="form-control">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">

</form>
```

---

Using a filtered method using PHP's [`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) filter.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $to = $_POST['to'];
    $me = "you@example.com";
    $to = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $to);

foreach(explode(",", $to) as $mailto){
   if(!filter_var($mailto, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
       { die("Sorry."); }

else{

    $subject = 'Message subject from ' . $name; // optional variable
    $message = "Hello there.";

    $headers = "From: {$me}\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: {$mailto}\r\n";

if(mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $headers)){
echo "Mail sent to $mailto ";
            }
        }

    }


} // brace for isset

?>

<form action="" method="post">

<input type="text" name="to" class="form-control">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">

</form>
```

Comment: Picking up on that whitespace ;) was actually going to comment saying `"don't forget the white space"` but I read your answer again and saw how stupid i was haha

Comment: @Darren I noticed your edit; don't be too hard on yourself. I'm sure you get tired eyes just like the next guy. `$next_guy="Me too";` ;)

Comment: I wouldn't have gone much further than `explode()` if I had answerred. Very well done sir.

Comment: @JohnConde I enjoyed building it, and mille grazie signore John :)