# mail() function not sending more than one email

Tags: php, email

Using `mail()` function i can send one email without a problem. But when i try to send a second email I receive the first but not the second.

```
$s1 = mail("info1@domain.com", $subject, $message, $headers);
$s2 = mail("info2@domain.com", $subject, $message, $headers);
$s3 = $s1 && $s2;
```

And `$s3` is `TRUE`.
I have tried sending two email in one mail call:

```
mail("info1@domain.com, info2@domain.com", $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Still only the first is sent but not the second.
How i can solve it? Of course the email addresses are all valid and none are  in spam folders.

Comment: the question's too unclear and pseudo code just doesn't hold much water

Comment: The problem not is about code, becouse all it work fine with one only email. Just only when i try to add a second email, then are problem. But if need i can update it, of course. Was just for understand from what depend it.

Comment: There are far too many duplicates for this. Here are a few https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708997/php-form-send-email-to-multiple-recipients --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506078/php-send-mail-to-multiple-email-addresses and your post does not contain enough code to support the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your question, but if you want to send email to multiple users, then try this,

```
$recipients = [
    'email1@emai.com',
    'email2@emai.com',
];
$recipients = implode(',', $recipients); // your email address
mail($recipients, $email_subject, $msg);
```

Comment: Is that first line correct?  `$emails=recipients = [` looks like one too many equal signs.

Comment: Sorry typographical error. Edited

Comment: I have tried to do so too, reading other post here about these problem, but not solved :(

Comment: What about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541839/php-send-mail-form-to-multiple-email-addresses?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure how have you added your headers but try and add this while declaring headers:

```
$headers .= 'Cc: info2@domain.com' . "\r\n";
```

so copying the email to the 2nd email address.